# Error when adding bootstrap to an angular-cli project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-ui-bootstrap

Getting this error while adding bootstrap into an angular project using angular-cli

```html
npm install bootstrap@3 jquery --save
npm ERR! path C:\Users\cw\Desktop\Basic-angular\got\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\cw\Desktop\Basic-angular\got\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\cw\Desktop\Basic-angular\got\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\cw\\Desktop\\Basic-angular\\got\\node_modules\\.staging\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\cw\\Desktop\\Basic-angular\\got\\node_modules\\.staging' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cw\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-18T11_54_33_403Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Hello! Please add an actual question to your description. in this current state, this is not a question and should be removed. please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The error message says "Run this command as administrator". If you are using cmd, try running cmd as an administrator.

Comment: How I use cmd as an administrator

Comment: On the Start menu, type cmd in the search field. Right click on Cmd application and click "Run as administrator"

Comment: Now it says npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.